# How to User Modelviz.py to Create a Django Diagram

Tags: django, diagram

My Django application structure looks like this:

```
MyProject
    |____templates
    |____static
    |____apps
    |   |____first_app
    |   |____second_pass
    |____settgins.py
    |____...
```

and I'm on Windows. Where do I have to paste **modelviz.py**? and also what command do I have to run to make it work? When I paste modelviz.py in apps and run

```
d:\projects\MyProject\apps> python modelviz.py first_app > diagram_1.dot
```

I get an error

```
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SE
TTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable first. In [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/) you will find that you can do this with

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
```

under Windows...

Comment: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE problem. But what command should I write when my settings.py file is in the root directory and all my apps are in the apps directory - I had to move my apps out of the apps folder just to test this.